# got error in sql query with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

I try to run an sql query (mssql 2005) like the following:

```
select top 20 d_date, date1, date2 
from reestr_calculated 
where reestr_id=2 
group by date2 
order by date2 desc
```

and I get the following error:

> Column 'reestr_calculated.d_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Does anybody know how can I deal with that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY`, multiple rows get "collapsed" to one row. To determine which of those rows in a group should be displayed, you have to use an aggregate function.

Like `MIN()` or `SUM()` or others.

Like this:

```
select top 20 MIN(d_date), MAX(date1), date2 
from reestr_calculated 
where reestr_id=2 
group by date2 
order by date2 desc
```

or like this:

```
select top 20 d_date, date1, date2 
from reestr_calculated 
where reestr_id=2 
group by d_date, date1, date2 
order by date2 desc
```

Answer (score 3):

All the column names present in `SELECT` must be present in `GROUP BY` unless you are using aggregate functions. Hence, add date1 also in group by.

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping by `date2`, which means returning one row for each `date2` value. Each `date2` value could have multiple `d_date` or `date1` values, so SQL doesn't know which values to return for each one.

As the error says, you either need an aggregate function (`MAX()`, `MIN()`, `AVG()` etc) or to include the other columns in the GROUP BY clause